# How to make like global variable which refreshes itself from db

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have program which is running forever (while True) and that is ok, but I need inside to use number which represents number of users in table (it isn't necessary  to be precise so I wnat to avoid COUNT(*) query to database whenever I need that number, but problem is when it has large error between real number and that number). I thought to make that my number refreshes every day. How to make like global variable which refreshes itself with but not to running forever (when it refreshes it doesn't use any CPU time) ?

Comment: It will surely use CPU time. Do you mean, that when it queries the database, the program execution should not wait until the database answers?

Answer (score 4):

Use a class property and only hit the server again if some time has elapsed.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

class MyThing(object):

    def __init__(self, refresh_interval=60*60*24):
        self.refresh_interval = refresh_interval
        self._n_users = None
        self._last_refresh = datetime.now() - timedelta(0, refresh_interval)
        # setup db connection stuff

    @property
    def n_users(self):
        if (datetime.now() - self._last_refresh).total_seconds() > self.refresh_interval:
            self._n_users = self.fetch_from_db()
            self._last_refresh = datetime.now()
        return self._n_users

    def fetch_from_db(self):
        # TODO
        return random.randint(0, 100)

t = MyThing(refresh_interval=3)
print t.n_users
```

Comment: This is a smarter solution, even though it's not what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Use a thread and make it sleep between attempts to update the variable.

```
#!python2

import threading
import time

global_count = 0

def UpdateUserCount():
    while True:
        # code to update user count
        # global_count = ...

        time.sleep(86400); # one day


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thr = threading.Thread( target=UpdateUserCount )
    thr.start()


    # Do other stuff.
```